# UITapGestureRecognizer not working inside of custom class (that's not a view controller)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom class Overlay where I added UIButton. When the button is clicked, a method should be called:

```
class Overlay {

func show(onView view: UIView, frame: CGRect) {
    let dismissButton = UIButton()
        dismissButton.frame = frame
        dismissButton.setTitle("Dismiss", for: .normal)
        dismissButton.setTitleColor(Project.Color.failure, for: .normal)
        dismissButton.titleLabel?.font = Project.Typography.lightFont.withSize(22)
        view.addSubview(dismissButton)

        dismissButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissBtnTapped(tap:)))
        dismissButton.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func dismissBtnTapped(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("TEST")
}
```

I call `show(...)` inside my ViewController, passing in its view and a frame.

But the tapGestrueRecognizer is not working. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Edit: I tried putting this code directly inside my ViewController. Then it works. I'm not sure why, though, and that's not a viable solution for me, unfortunately :/

Edit 2: 
That's how I call it:

```
let overlay = Overlay()
overlay.show(onView: self.view, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 150))
```

Comment: why you are adding `tapgesturerecognizer` on button?? you can directly write action method for it!

Comment: How do you "attach" that overlay to your view controller ?

Comment: I tried `dismissButton.addTarget(...)` but it didn't work. What do you mean by "attaching" that overlay?

Comment: Can you put more code from your viewController that how you are making calls and how using your customView - overlay .

Comment: I edited my question. Currently, that's all there is in my overlay. I'm just building it right now

Comment: I have the suspicion that UIGestureRecognizers only work inside of ViewControllers ( so that the target in `UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, ...)` refers to that ViewController). Not sure, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already adding a button try adding a target to it instead of a gesture,
and make your overlay variable global.

```
class YourControllerClass: UIViewController {
let overlay = Overlay()
...
func show(onView: UIView, frame: CGRect) {
...
dismissButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissBtnTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}

func dismissBtnTapped(sender:UIButton){

}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: are you adding more then one overlay on to your view?

Comment: Make your let overlay = Overlay() global and everything should work fine

Comment: I'm probably just too stupid right now, but it works, if I add the `tap recognizer` to the `view`, but it does not work if I add it to the `dismissButton`

Comment: Wait, you edited your answer. Now you put the `show`method inside the ViewController, but I need it to be in a separate class.

Comment: Update: Okay, I got it working by rewriting everything. Not sure what was wrong but now it works with your trick :)

Answer (score 1):

You not need to add `tapgesturerecognizer` on `uibutton`, you can directly add target on it something like,

```
   dismissButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissBtnTapped), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

and remove parameter from `dismissBtnTapped` method!

Comment: see comments above

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `view` which you are passing as `onView` in `show(onView: UIView, frame: CGRect)` method is enabled for user interactions.

Comment: Yeah, it is enabled

Answer (score 0):

As an example my script

step 1

```
class MyIcon {

var targetController = UIViewController()

func show(_ targetController:UIViewController, _ view: UIView, _ frame: CGRect) {

    self.targetController = targetController

    let icon = UIImageView()
    icon.frame = frame
    icon.image = UIImage(named: "image_user.png")
    icon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addSubview(icon)

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.targetController, action: #selector(iconTapped))
    icon.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func iconTapped(_ icon: UIImageView) {
    print("Yo hoo! This worked!")
}
}
```

step 2

```
class MyController: UIViewController{
    let myicon = MyIcon()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myicon.show(self, self.view, self.view.frame)
    }

 @IBAction func iconTapped(_ icon: UIImageView){
       myicon.iconTapped(icon)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non of the above solve the problem here.
The point is, if you create the instance of the custom class inside of an event the instance is deleted after the event is completed since it is not associated with any persistent element in your app. Thats why you have to instantiate the object of the class as an attribute of the superview.